# display row content to a form

Tags: php, html, sql

i have a table that displays data searched.
what i want to happen is when after i click the row, that data from that row clicked will be displayed in a form.

**displaying the table**:
search.php

```
echo '<table id="patientTable" class="w3-table-all w3-hoverable">'
echo '<tr class="w3-yellow"><th>Admission No</th><th>Hospital No</th><th>Patient Name</th></tr>';
                while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                    echo '<tr onclick=patientClick(this)>';
                        foreach($row as $key=>$value) {
                        echo '<td>',$value,'</td>';
                        //echo $i;
                    }
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
            echo '</table><br />';
```

the script to attempt to connect to form

```
function patientClick(x){
    var rowInd = x.rowIndex;
    var adNo = document.getElementById("patientTable").rows[rowInd].cells[0].innerHTML
    var hosNo = document.getElementById("patientTable").rows[rowInd].cells[1].innerHTML;
    var patname = document.getElementById("patientTable").rows[rowInd].cells[2].innerHTML;
    alert(adNo +"-"+ hosNo +"-"+ patname);//check to display row content

    var jsObj = {patname:patname, adNo:adNo, hosNo:hosNo}
    $.post('addPN.php', {data:jsObj}, function(data){
        $('#displayPatient').html(data);
    });
}
```

the form to display so to save more data
addPN.php

```
    <?php
    $arr = json_decode(json_encode($_POST["data"]),true);
    $adNo = $arr[0]['adNo'];
    $hosNo = $arr[1]['hosNo'];
    $patname = $arr[2]['patname'];

    echo $adNo;//check to display
    echo $hosNo;//check to display
    echo $patname;//check to display
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action = "savePN.php" id = "savePNotes" method = "POST">
            <input type = "submit" id = "updateButton" value = "Save">
            <input type = "text" readonly = "true" id = "adNo" name = "adNo" value = "<?php echo $adNo;?>">
            <input type = "text" readonly = "true" id = "hosNo" name = "hosNo" value = "<?php echo $hosNo;?>">
            <input type = "text" readonly = "true" id = "patname" name = "patname" value = "<?php echo $patname;?>">
            <input type = "text" id = "cn" name = "cn" placeholder = "Contact Number">
            <input type = "text" id = "cadd" name = "cadd" placeholder = "Address">
            <input type = "text" id = "ctype" name = "ctype" placeholder = "Type">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<br> id: ". $row["id"]. " - Name: ". $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"] . "<br>";
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Answer (score 0):

this is a bad practice using php as a client, but ajax is one way communication that you cant redirect instantly in serverside

```
function patientClick(x){
    var rowInd = x.rowIndex;
    var adNo = document.getElementById("patientTable").rows[rowInd].cells[0].innerHTML
    var hosNo = document.getElementById("patientTable").rows[rowInd].cells[1].innerHTML;
    var patname = document.getElementById("patientTable").rows[rowInd].cells[2].innerHTML;
    alert(adNo +"-"+ hosNo +"-"+ patname);//check to display row content

    //here you must construct some JSON object for your data
    var jsObj = { pathname: pathname,
                  adNo: adNo,
                  hosNo: hosNo }
    $.post('searchPatient.php', JSON.stringify({ data : jsObj}) , function(data){
            $("#displayPatient").html(data);
        });

}
```

in your server side you should decode your json

use this 
 $data = `json_decode($_POST["data"])`
 echo $data["adNo"];

and i think you structure is no good and i think its not possible to do what you wanted to do because the form are from php and different file maybe its possible if you use just normal html form so can easily manipulate the form using DOM

Comment: thank you.ill try this one. i know its a bad practice to use php as client.ill try to modify my code

Comment: <?php
 json_decode($_POST["data"]);
 if(isset($_POST['adNo'])){ $adNo = $_POST['adNo']; }
 if(isset($_POST['hosNo'])){ $hosNo = $_POST['hosNo']; }
 if(isset($_POST['patname'])){ $patname = $_POST['patname']; }
 
 echo $adNo;//check to display
 echo $hosNo;//check to display
 echo $patname;//check to display
?>

Comment: <input type = "text" readonly = "true" id = "adNo" name = "adNo" value = "$adNo">
  <input type = "text" readonly = "true" id = "hosNo" name = "hosNo" value = "$hosNo">
  <input type = "text" readonly = "true" id = "patname" name = "patname" value = "$patname">
  <input type = "text" id = "cn" name = "cn" placeholder = "Contact Number">
  <input type = "text" id = "cadd" name = "cadd" placeholder = "Address">
  <input type = "text" id = "ctype" name = "ctype" placeholder = "Type">

Comment: but im getting this.

Comment: Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\cnc\addPN.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined variable: adNo in C:\xampp\htdocs\cnc\addPN.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined variable: hosNo in C:\xampp\htdocs\cnc\addPN.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined variable: patname in C:\xampp\htdocs\cnc\addPN.php on line 9

Comment: expects parameter 1 to be string...
in my json_decode

Comment: @phloxangrex hello sorry for the late reply but your using it wrong, you should use it like this 

      $data = json_decode($_POST["data"], true) 
     
     to check it 
   
    echo $data["adNo"]

Comment: thanks.but im getting this error......
Fatal error: Function name must be a string. in the json_decode line..

Comment: try to change echo $data["adNo"] into println($data) and let me see i think you got error on extracting json_decode

Comment: it is still the same

Comment: first you need to stringify your json before sending that data using ajax to your back end

Comment: i have some simple project its not yet completed but you can see the codes so you will have an idea https://github.com/Try-Parser/

Comment: i did your stringify.the problem is still the same

Comment: $.post('searchPatient.php',{ data :  JSON.stringify(jsObj)} , function(data){
            $("#displayPatient").html(data);
        });

did you mean this did you try it ?